# How to display nice vectors using T1 encoding?

Tags: font-encodings, vector

There seem to be a clash between two things I usually do but had never done simultaneously: using the T1 font encoding and using `\overrightarrow` for vectors.

Indeed, I find the `\vec` arrow's fixed size ugly. For example like this: [image: equation showcasing the little arrows]

So what I usually do is `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}` which outputs nice long arrows (at least in OT1 encoding).

Although, I have to use the T1 encoding for my current document but it seems to mess with the arrows. For example here, the arrow is too long on the left: [image]

I could provide my whole preamble if the font encoding is not the problem but it's quite long.

So the question is: how to have both a correct encoding (my document is in French) and nice arrows over my vectors?

**EDIT: adding an example** (after @DavidCarlisle's request)

I found what caused the font change: the `newtxmath` package. I had used it to be able to use `\not` with anything I want. After examination, I happen to prefer the original `\vec` command applied on single characters with the `newtxmath` font.

Here is the example anyway:

```tex
% Set up the document's format to A4 and the font's size to 12pt.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% Set up the input's encoding to UTF-8, the document's font and language to T1 (adapted to french) and french (the grammar linter uses this parameter).
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Allows to define \notfoo or \nfoo (not recommended) in order for \not\foo to work as wished.
\usepackage{newtxmath}

% Redefines \vec such that the arrow covers the whole name of the vector.
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\overrightarrow{#1}}

\begin{document}
\(\vec{v}\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: `\vec` is intended to be used on just _one_ symbol. In your example, it should be set only on the `p`, `\nu` or `u`, respectively, excluding indices and such.

Comment: it is hard to comment if you show no code. Unless you are doing something non standard specifying `T1` as in `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`  has no effect at all on math mode so it is hard to guess what the question is refering to

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess it's probably related to something else then. I'm going to look for the problem

Comment: @RomainBricout if you provided an example,  someone could debug it for you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the thing is my preamble is really long and I can't quite figure out what matters and what doesn't. Anyways, I decided to follow @schtandard's advice and to use the original `\vec` with all the stuff outside of it. Thank you both!

Comment: It is easy for you to make a small example.  just use `\documentclass{article}.. your preamble.. \begin{document} $\vec{v}$ \end{document}` then delete every line of the preamble you can delete while still showing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the new [`pdfmsym`](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdfmsym/0) “package” (it isn't in the sense of LaTeX).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\input{pdfmsym}% not \usepackage!
\pdfmsymsetscalefactor{8}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\[
\diff\vecc{p_{\mathrm{atome}}}=
\vecc{p_f} - \vecc{p_i}=
m\vecc{v'}-m\shortvecc{v}=
-2mu\vecc{u_x}
\]

\[
\diff\vec{p}_{\mathrm{atome}}=
\vec{p}_f - \vec{p}_i=
m\vec{v}^{\,\prime}-m\vec{v}=
-2mu\vec{u}_x
\]

\end{document}
```

I'd much prefer the latter format, though.

[image]

I see no difference if I add

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

If I use `\overrightarrow`, I get something like

[image]

which, I'm afraid, can hardly be described as “nice”. But I get no difference with or without T1.